# String matching on a field in a table and another field in a foreign table

Tags: prisma

I have a `Brand` table and `Product` table, which have 1-to-many relations.
`Product` table has `brandId` column, and I am trying to do a search on `Product` name and `Brand` name.

Let's say I have the following brands - products:

```
Samsung - Galaxy S20 Smartphone
Samsung - Galaxy Tab 7 Tablet
Apple - iPhone 14 Pro Max
```

Here's what I expect in terms of query and the results:
Query: 'Samsung'
Results:

```
Samsung - Galaxy S20 Smartphone
Samsung - Galaxy Tab 7 Tablet
```

Query: 'Sams Gal Smartph'
Results:

```
Samsung - Galaxy S20 Smartphone
```

How can I implement this? Looks easy enough (every word in query should be in 'brand name' + 'product name'), but it's somehow not easy because of the fact that the brand name is in a separate table from `Product`. Also, it feels like doing a join for every row and iterating every word in query string could be expensive.

---

Here are my model definitions:

```
model Product {
  id                String          @id @default(cuid())
  name              String
  brand             Brand           @relation(fields: [brandId], references: [id])
  brandId           Int
  // ...
}

model Brand {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String    @unique @db.Citext
  products  Product[]
  // ...
}
```

and got the following query work:

```
const queryWords = query
  .replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, "")
  .split(" ");
await prisma.product.findMany({
  where: {
    AND: queryWords.map((word) => {
      return {
        OR: [
          {
            name: {
              contains: word,
              mode: "insensitive",
            },
          },
          {
            brand: {
              name: {
                contains: word,
                mode: "insensitive",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      };
    }),
  },
  include: {
    brand: true,
  },
});
```

However, is this going to be efficient? Should I use full-text search instead?

Answer (score 0):

Prisma launched Full Text Search behind a feature flag which enables you to search text fields on your model:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/full-text-search

You could use this to query each model's name for whether or not the search is satisfied from your query.

Example of submitting a search query for multiple words; https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/full-text-search#querying-the-database

You can use this to write a Prisma query which says "Find any product item for which the product name can search these words OR its related brand can search these words." Without knowing your Prisma schema it's hard to say exactly what the query will be, but Full Text Search should get you a lot of the way there.

Comment: Thanks, but I am having difficulty searching on a relation field (Brand name). From what I've read so far, it looked like I need to create a materialized view with both brand name and product name? Also, materialized views are not supported natively by Prisma. Do you have an example code snippet I can try?

Comment: If a Brand is connected to your Product via a relation field, you can absolutely search for what the name of the related Brand is when also searching for a product. Without seeing your Prisma schema it makes it harder for me to help you further. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#filter-by-related-record-field-values

Comment: I have updated the question body with my schema snippet and the prisma API call snippet. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: I made it work using 'contains' queries. However, is this going to be efficient? Should I use full-text search instead?

Comment: Both approaches would work. If you are getting any performance issues then you can try to optimise it by doing full-text search and then comparing the response times.